# Sas - Keeping Proc Means Output of Mean by Class

Tags: sas, proc

```
data braindata;
infile "C:\Users\shockwavemasta\Downloads\brain-data.txt"
firstobs = 3 /* data starts on line 3, not on line 1 or 2 in the file*/
expandtabs /* change tabs into 8 spaces each */
pad; /* pads each entry with spaces as needed */
/* The variable names are taken from the file header.
E.g., @9 HourDrawn 3. means the value of the hour variable is           
located at column 9 and uses 3 characters to express the number.
*/
input @9 HourDrawn 3. @17 Sex $1. @22 Concentration 11.;
hr = HourDrawn;
run;

proc sort data = braindata out = brainmean_sorted;
by sex;
run;

proc means data = brainmean_sorted;
by sex; class hr;
output out=BrainMeans mean=mean;
run;
```

This is what I have so far and it outputs with the mean equal to HR which is not what I want at all, when it should be taking the means of each class of hr and retaining the values. What am I doing wrong?

Currently looks like this:

[image]

When I want it to retain the values in Concentration that it prints out:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for editing! Now if only somebody could help me out haha

Comment: Please do not start a new question like this - you should have edited your other question. Please delete the other question now.

Answer (score 0):

As stated elsewhere, you need a VAR statement.

```
proc means data = brainmean_sorted;
by sex; class hr;
var concentration;
output out=BrainMeans 
mean(concentration)=mean;
run;
```